# Odoo notification, your database is expiring in 10 days. you have more users than your subscription allows

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a licenced enterprise version of ODOO installed (on premise) on one of my aws servers. I am getting an error that says

```
Your database is expiring in 10 days. you have more users than your subscription allows.
```

[image]

Before this error came in i had around 10 users, but i think my subscription only allowed 5 users. Anyways i have removed the rest and now i just have 5 users in the system. Why am i still getting this error? Do i have to do something on my end?

I am using the latest version of odoo.

Comment: This is an issue for odoo support https://www.odoo.com/help not SO

Answer (score 1):

What you will have to do in order to be sure that your DB and your license are aligned is to proceed manually to a user check.
Here is the process to follow:

1/ go to debug mode
2/ go to "Settings

This should then have as a result that your license and DB will be aligned and then the message shouldn't appear anymore.

Comment: i have the same problem 
what about activate developer mode and go to settings ?
another question : is license has limited number of users ?